# How can I print these entire arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm wanting to print these entire arrays, there should be 100 words and the counts on every word, how many times it was used. How can I print the entire StringArray and the entire IntArray?

```
package program6;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Program6 {

static String[] stringArray = new String[100];
static int[] intArray = new int[100];
static String fileName = "myths.txt";

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));


    do {
        String word = input.next();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

            stringArray[i] = word;
            if (word.equals(stringArray[i])) {
                intArray[i] += 1;

            }
        }

    } while (input.hasNext());

    System.out.println("Myths of Babylonia and Assyria");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringArray) + Arrays.toString(intArray));






}
}
```

Comment: You've changed your question around a fair bit.  If you have a separate question to ask, feel free to ask it, but don't change the existing question you have, or you risk invalidating existing answers.

Comment: aside from the printing your code won't work as you always assign the word to a new index and then increment the word count by one, but you never reevaluate that values. Maybe an array is the wrong way to go here (Use a `List` and its `.indexOf()` method)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(StringArray));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(IntArray));
```

Also note, convention mandates that variables are camel-cased and that classes begin with a capital letter.  Further note that the use of brackets is only necessary when indexing into an array, or declaring an initial size of an array.

Comment: Ah thank you very much, for some reason its just printing a tun of null's and 0's any reason why that would be?

Comment: That prints the contents of the array.  You get null and zero if the array contains that.  Something isn't being added to the array; I leave you to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
System.out.println(StringArray[]) + (IntArray[]);
```

You need to iterate your arrays, perhaps like this -

```
for (int i = 0; i < StringArray.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(StringArray[i] + " " + IntArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why it would be printing null and 0's ?

Comment: You didn't store anything on those indexes.

Comment: Wait what? I thought my do while loop stored the first 100 words from my textfile into the array.

Comment: No.... you'd need something like `StringArray[i] = word;` after `String word = input.next();` and you'd need to keep track of how many words you've read... etc.

Comment: Ah thanks, I edited the code above, could you look at it? What else do I need to do?

Comment: I ran it, it is just printing one word over and over, with [568] out to the right.